# Hibernate Validator Not Correctly Displaying Unicode Characters

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, internationalization

I am building a Spring MVC web application that uses JSR-303 validation. With the first form I created, I added a couple of validation annotations (including custom error message codes) to the form backing bean. I also created ValidationMessages.properties and ValidationMessages_en.properties files.

Everything seems to be working correctly with one exception: multi-byte utf-8 encoded characters are not displayed correctly (e.g., "ñ" is displayed as "Ã±").

This is not a problem with my standard messages.properties and messages_en.properties files that I use for field labels and other text, so I'm assuming it's an issue with the hibernate validator code. Has anyone else had this issue and solved it? FYI, I'm using Hibernate version 4.3.0.Final.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my properties files I must include special characters like this:
\u00F3 instead of ó

In that way they are shown well.

Hope it helps.

P.S.: Using ResourceBundleEditor from Eclipse also helps.

Comment: This should not be necessary. Standard messages.properties files work correctly. Also, for very large properties files, it is unreasonable to expect a translator to manually look up and change all special characters to their unicode equivalent.